# DotLESS - Error - Expected unitless number in function 'percentage'

Tags: dotless

I'm calling DotLess via MSBuild.

Here's my file:

```
@import "variables.less";
@media all and (min-width: @break-mobile) {

  .page-container {

    .main {
  float: right;
  width: percentage(700/@siteMaxWidth);
}
  }
}
```

"variables.less" contains:

```
/* defaults */
@siteMaxWidth: 1070px;
```

On compilation, I receive this error:

```
Expected unitless number in function 'percentage', found 0.654205607px on line 9 in file
```

This compiles well in CodeKit.

Are there any DotLESS experts that might help?

Comment: This is a random shot in the dark since I don't know dotless, but what if you do `(700px/@siteMaxWidth)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the unit tests related to the [PercentageFixture](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/blob/master/src/dotless.Test/Specs/Functions/PercentageFixture.cs) which looks like this:

```
AssertExpression("25%", "percentage(25px / 100px)");
```

It looks like if you specify the `px` unit for the `700` value as well, it should work:

```
width: percentage(700px/@siteMaxWidth);
```

Comment: I don't know DotLESS/LESS so if this is indeed wrong, let me know and I'll edit/delete the answer as appropriate.